# Easiest way to fix faulty redirects to mobile site?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have a mobile version of my website but the problem I have is that it has faulty redirects.

Both sites have the same permalink except it redirects to m.mysite.com homepage for every link. Eg. Mysite.com/about redirects to m.mysite.com

What's the easiest and simplest way to correct this? Im using wordpress

Comment: I use the .htaccess to address any redirect issues and/or needs.

Comment: Can you provide the .htaccess you are using and can you please provide the conditions that should result in redirecting the user? I have something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]` in mind.